# How do I create a RDLC report in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc, visual-studio-2019

I installed the [report designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001) but after doing so I see no report templates in Visual Studio in the create file dialog - how do I create a report?

edit: every time I start Visual Studio now (after installing the report designer) I see this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that for whatever reason, the report templates only appear when creating a new file inside an ASP.NET project. I was originally testing with a console project just to play around but I have to do it in an ASP.NET project instead.